How to disable/enable uwsgi web server from SSH CLI?
I have an embedded Linux system in a cellular modem with a web gui as well as SSH access. For security, I would like to be able to enable the web gui from SSH when it is needed, and otherwise disable it. The environment is loosely based on OpenWRT, but the web server implementation is different, using uwsgi instead of the typical use of uhttpd.
I have reviewed articles on uswgi managment and the "Emperor mode" that is in use.
The system is using uswgi version 2.0.18.
I tried # /etc/init.d/uwsgi stop and # /etc/init.d/uwsgi disable. There was no error message (or any message) displayed, but the web gui remains available.  The init.d file looks like this:
# cat /etc/init.d/uwsgi
#!/bin/sh /etc/rc.common

START=79
USE_PROCD=1

start_service() {
        procd_open_instance
        procd_set_param command /usr/sbin/uwsgi --ini /etc/uwsgi/emperor.ini
        procd_set_param stderr 1
        procd_set_param file /etc/uwsgi/emperor.ini
        procd_set_param respawn
        procd_close_instance
}

After running # /etc/init.d/uwsgi stop and # /etc/init.d/uwsgi disable, I looked in the system log and found this:
2024 Nov 30 18:41:02 E1500-4 lua: luci: accepted login on /admin/system/flash for root from 10.0.0.12
2024 Nov 30 18:41:17 E1500-4 uwsgi[4687]: *** has_emperor mode detected (fd: 8) ***
2024 Nov 30 18:41:17 E1500-4 uwsgi[4687]: [uWSGI] getting INI configuration from /etc/uwsgi/vassals/luci-cgi_io.ini
2024 Nov 30 18:41:17 E1500-4 uwsgi[4687]: Sat Nov 30 18:41:17 2024 - [emperor] vassal /etc/uwsgi/vassals/luci-cgi_io.ini has been spawned
2024 Nov 30 18:41:17 E1500-4 uwsgi[4687]: Sat Nov 30 18:41:17 2024 - [emperor] vassal /etc/uwsgi/vassals/luci-cgi_io.ini is ready to accept requests
2024 Nov 30 18:41:17 E1500-4 uwsgi[4687]: Sat Nov 30 18:41:17 2024 - [emperor] vassal /etc/uwsgi/vassals/luci-cgi_io.ini is now loyal

Possibly the "Emperor Mode" is re-spawning the server. Is there another service to stop the "emperor", or tell it to ignore certain apps? Can anyone point me to a reference on temporarily enabling and disabling server apps in a uwsgi emperor mode environment?

This was user error - I was accidentally testing the HTTPS availability on a different instance of the system than the one I was connected to via SSH.
These commands do work as expected:
# /etc/init.d/uwsgi stop
# /etc/init.d/uwsgi disable

# /etc/init.d/uwsgi enable
# /etc/init.d/uwsgi start

Hopefully this is helpful to others as I found relatively little information on uwsgi.
